# How to make tp-link access point bring wifi and splitter?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, wireless-bridge

I have just bought that product:

http://www.tp-link.com/eg/products/details/cat-12_TL-WA901ND.html

I'm trying to make this device connect into a WIFI network called for example: `Network 1`, And the repeat the `Network 1` with new name for example: `Network 2` While pulling RJ45(Ethernet cable) from the device to a Switch So I can split the cable.

Is it possible to do this multiple actions with this device?

I have created a draw to make you understand what I mean.
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: What you are trying to do is a bit unclear. Why would you not simply plug the WAN port of this device into the switch and configure it as Network2?

Comment: I don't have the option to plug WAN port, its 2 home units, I can't take cable from my parents home into mine.

Comment: Sorry, I only glanced at the device you purchased - I thought it was a router, its an AP.  That said, I see no reason you could not plug it into a LAN port then - no need to connect it via WIFI.   (I was talking about a WAN port because in a router you would have to deal with DHCP. As this will not be a DHCP server you can plug it into the WAN Interface.